# Can't load PostGIS partitionned table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I partitionned a table (over 13 millions geographic point data) in my PostgreSQL database with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE data.data_fusion (
 id                BIGINT NOT NULL,
 source            TEXT,
 id_source         VARCHAR,
 id_vn             INTEGER,
 taxref_id         INTEGER,
 ...
 geom              GEOMETRY(Point, 2154),
 equipe            VARCHAR,
 exp_excl          BOOLEAN
 )
PARTITION BY LIST (equipe);
```

And for each child table I did create primary key and indexes like in this example.

```
CREATE TABLE data.data_fusion_lpo07 PARTITION OF data.data_fusion FOR VALUES IN ('lpo07');
ALTER TABLE data.data_fusion_lpo07 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
CREATE INDEX ON data.data_fusion_lpo07 (source);
CREATE INDEX ON data.data_fusion_lpo07 (id_vn);
CREATE INDEX ON data.data_fusion_lpo07 (taxref_id);
CREATE INDEX ON data.data_fusion_lpo07 (nom_vern);
CREATE INDEX ON data.data_fusion_lpo07 (nom_sci);
CREATE INDEX ON data.data_fusion_lpo07 USING GIST (geom);
CREATE INDEX ON data.data_fusion_lpo07 (equipe);
CREATE INDEX ON data.data_fusion_lpo07 (code_nidif_oiseau);
```

Actually, there is no problem to load child tables in my QGIS project, but I'm unable to load parent table 'data.data_fusion'. I've got the following error messages:

- Using browser panel:

  ```
  Layer is not valid: The layer dbname='dbwork' host=bdd.faura.org port=5432 sslmode=require authcfg=lpoaura srid=2154 type=Point table="data"."data_fusion" (geom) sql= is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map
  ```
- Using add layer menu

  ```
  dbname='dbwork' host=bdd.faura.org port=5432 sslmode=require authcfg=lpoaura key='""' estimatedmetadata=true srid=2154 type=Point table="data"."data_fusion" (geom) sql= is an invalid layer - not loaded
  ```

PostgreSQL console indicates an pk issue (no pk on parent table):

```
  Unexpected relation type 'p'.
  PostgreSQL layer has no primary key.
```

Is there a way to load my parent partitionned table into QGIS (v 2.18.14) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like [native PostgreSQL partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) isn't supported in QGIS 2.x. It should work as expected in QGIS 3.
See related [ticket](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17302) and [commit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/f243b844).

As a workaround, you could create a view that's just a `SELECT *` from your master table and bring that into QGIS.

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me. Even whith row level security enabled on table! Actually, i can't migrate to newer version of qgis, there is a problem connection to postgresql with secure ssl protocol, like mentionned in this issue: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17672